# バイトオーダーについて教えてください

Tags: linux

リトルエンディアン環境で、C言語で文字列をファイルに書き込み、そのファイルから再度読み込むプロセスについてお聞きします。

コード例：

```
char ch[]="AB”；
```

実行中のchの先頭アドレスにはAが格納されていることは理解しました。

ABをファイルに出力すると、当然ファイルの内容はABというテキストとなると思います。

今度は、ファイルからABをメモリに読みこもうとすると、リトルエンディアンなのでメモリ的にはBAという順番になるかと思いますが、実際はファイルの内容がそのまま（ABとして）ストアされていました。

readシステムコールがバイトオーダーを考慮してスワップ処理しているのか?
１byteずつAとBを読み込んでいるのか?

どういう仕組みでバイトオーダーが処理されているのか理解できません。

Answer (score 6):

まず、バイトオーダーはファイルに保存する際に発生するものではなく、メモリ内に保存されている時点ですでに発生しているものです。

また、バイトオーダーにより、配列内の**要素の順番**が変わることはありません。

```c
char ch[]="AB";
```

こちらの配列は、ビッグエンディアンでもリトルエンディアンでも、以下の順番で保存されます。

| アドレス | 値 |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | 'A' |
| 0001 | 'B' |
| 0002 | '\0' |

バイトオーダーで変わるのは、配列内の**各々の要素のバイト順**です。
例えば、`short`が2バイトだったとして、

```c
short s[] = {0x1234, 0x5678};
```

こちらの配列は、ビッグエンディアンだと以下の順番で保存されます。

| アドレス | 値 |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | 0x12 |
| 0001 | 0x34 |
| 0002 | 0x56 |
| 0003 | 0x78 |

リトルエンディアンだと以下の順番で保存されます。

| アドレス | 値 |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | 0x34 |
| 0001 | 0x12 |
| 0002 | 0x78 |
| 0003 | 0x56 |

ビッグエンディアンでもリトルエンディアンでも、配列の先頭の要素がアドレス0000～0001に、2番目の要素がアドレス0002～0003に保存されているというのは変わらないと分かると思います。

Answer (score 4):

「バイトオーダー」というのは2バイト以上のデータをバイト単位で表現する場合にどのような順番にするかという話です。`char`型のような1バイト単位で扱うデータについてはバイトオーダーは関係ありません。

---

以下、蛇足です。

質問のコードからC言語のことでの話を知りたいようなので、以下、C言語を前提で話をします。また、現在のほとんどの実装にあわせて、1バイトは8ビットとして話をします。

この「2バイト以上のデータ」というのはC言語における`short`型や`wchar_t`型のように2バイト以上の整数型のことです(`float`等の浮動小数点数型はそもそも実装依存であり、バイトオーダーという考え型自体がない)。`char`型は1バイトの整数型であり、その配列である`char[]`型もバイトオーダーは関係ありません。

バイトオーダーが関係するのは2バイト以上のデータ(数値)をメモリ上やバイトストリーム上で表現したときにどうなるかです。メモリ上のデータのバイトオーダーは環境依存であり、C言語であれば、共用体を使うことで確認できます。

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union uint {
    uint8_t u8[8];
    uint16_t u16[4];
    uint32_t u32[2];
    uint64_t u64[1];
};

int main(void)
{
    union uint i;
    i.u64[0] = UINT64_C(81985529216486895);
    printf("uint64_t: %016" PRIX64 "\n", i.u64[0]);
    printf("uint32_t: %08" PRIX32 " %08" PRIX32 "\n", i.u32[0], i.u32[1]);
    printf("uint16_t: %04" PRIX16 " %04" PRIX16 " %04" PRIX16 " %04" PRIX16
           "\n",
           i.u16[0], i.u16[1], i.u16[2], i.u16[3]);
    printf("uint8_t: %02" PRIX8 " %02" PRIX8 " %02" PRIX8 " %02" PRIX8
           " %02" PRIX8 " %02" PRIX8 " %02" PRIX8 " %02" PRIX8 "\n",
           i.u8[0], i.u8[1], i.u8[2], i.u8[3], i.u8[4], i.u8[5], i.u8[6],
           i.u8[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

最初のuint64_tの16進数での数値と比べて、uint8_tにしたとき、小さい順(リトルエンディアン)か大きい順(ビッグエンディアン)かを確認できるでしょう。例えば、x86_64のCPUを用いている環境ではリトルエンディアンであるため、一番最後は"EF CD AB 89 67 45 23 01"と表示されるでしょう。

バイトストリーム上の表現というのは、他のプログラムなどとデータをやり取り場合にどのような順番でバイトを渡すのかという話です。例えばネットワークの多くのプロトコルではビッグエンディアンを使用しています(そのため、ビッグエンディアンはネットワークバイトオーダーとも言われます)。IPアドレスは192.168.1.2のように表現しますが、実際は3232235778等の4バイト(32ビット)の数値です。ネットワークのパケットというのはバイト単位で(もっと下のデータリンク層ではビット単位)処理しますが、パケットの宛先として3232235778というIPアドレスを表現するは、0xC0(192)、0xA8(168), 0x01(1)、x02(2)という大きい順にしたデータをパケットに含めることになります。ネットワークのライブラリ等はこういった処理を環境のバイトオーダーに依存しない形で手動で行っていることになります。

上のことは2バイト以上の数値を表現するにはどのようにするのかの話です。数値を書き込む場合は`printf`等を用いて数値を数字のフォーマットに変換するため、バイトオーダーは関係無くなります。CPUが異なっても、数字の表現は変わりません。

文字列をファイルに保存の話に戻りましょう。最初にの述べたとおり、`char`型は1バイトであるため、バイトオーダーは関係ありません。`char`の配列を`fputs`等でそのまま書き込んだ場合、その配列の順番で各バイトが書き込まれることになります。ASCIIまたはASCII互換な文字コードの環境においては、`"AB"`という文字列は`{65, 66, 0}`という`char`の配列であり`fprintf(file, "AB");`は、fileに65('A'と言う文字)、66('B'という文字)が書き込まれることになりまうす(`fprintf`はnull文字で書き込みを停止するため、0は書き込まれません。)。この処理に65という`char`型の数値は1バイトの表現であるため、バイトオーダーとか全く関係無く、書き込まれることになります。また、`char`の配列は、UT8-8やWindows-31Jのような可変幅の文字符号化形式になっている場合もあります。可変幅の文字符号化形式ではASCII互換な部分は1文字1バイトに対して、それ以外の文字を2バイト以上で表現しますが、その2バイト以上は並びがセットであり、`short`のような一つの数値という訳ではありません。そのため、バイトオーダーというのものはなく、文字符号化形式での表現にそって書き込まれることになります。

では、文字列全てにおいてバイトオーダーが無関係であるかというとそうではありません。C言語には`wchar_t`型というワイド文字があり、これは2バイト以上の数値です。`wchar_t`型の文字符号化形式は環境依存であり、多くの場合はUTF-16またはUTF-32です。UTF-16もUTF-32も、UTF-8と同じくUnicodeの符号化形式ですが、UTF-8とは違い、UTF-16とUTF-32は一つの文字(データ)が2バイトまたは4バイトになるため、バイトオーダーという概念があります。メモリ上のバイト表現も、`short`等の2バイト以上の数値と同じように環境によってリトルエンディアンだったりビッグエンディアンだったりします。

このワイド文字をファイルに書き込む場合、`fputs`等の`char`型配列文や字列用の関数では無く`fputws`等の`wchar_t`型配列文字列用の関数を用いる必要があります。ここで注意すべき事は、`fputws`は、`fputs`のように文字のバイト表現をそのままファイルに書き込むのでは無く、書き込み先のIOで設定された文字コード(`fopen`等で"w,css=UTF-8"等のように指定する)、または、現在のロケール(`setlocale`関数で設定する)で指定された文字コードに変換されて書き込まれるということです。例えば、UTF-16LE(UTF-16のリトルエンディアン)が指定されている(`fopen("ファイル名", "w,css=UTF-16LE")`のように開く)場合は、`wchar_t`がUTF-16であろうが、UTF-32であろうが、環境がリトルエンディアンとかビッグエンディアンとか関係無く、ファイルにはリトルエンディアンのUTF-16としてのバイトの並びで文字に変換されて入力されることになります。これは、文字列がメモリ上の表現でバイトオーダーがどうなっているかは一切関係なく、ファイルを書き込み時に指定された文字符号化スキーム(先程の話のUTF-16LEのこと)によってバイトオーダーが決まることになります。

Answer (score 2):

> ファイルからABをメモリに読みこもうとすると、リトルエンディアンなのでメモリ的にはBAという順番になるかと思いますが

いいえ、ファイルI/Oはバイトオーダーの影響を受けません。書き込んだ順序通りに読み込めます。

Answer (score 1):

違う視点（ハードウエア側）から解説を試みるテスト

32bit CPU ってのは結局のところ内部の回路（バス）が３２本で構成されているから 32bit と呼ぶわけです。 64bit CPU はバスが６４本。 16bit CPU はバスが１６本。当然 8bit CPU はバスが８本。その昔には intel 8088 みたいな CPU もあったわけですがまあ例外。

んで 8bit CPU の時代に 8bit の塊をバイトと呼ぶことにして、そのバイト１つ１つに別のアドレスを振る習慣がついたわけです。でも 32bit CPU でデータバスが３２本ということは**ハードウエア上は**４バイトに同一のアドレスが振られていることになります。
# 16bit の場合も話は同様

既に稼働している 8bit CPU 用に書かれたソフトウエアは 8bit に別のアドレスを振り 8bit のバスアクセスをしているので、そのソフトウエアを 32bit CPU に移植する際には 32bit CPU であっても 8bit アクセスができるように回路を作ってもらえるとソフトウエア技術者としては助かるわけです。なので、たいていの 32bit CPU は３２本の線のうち８本だけを有効にして２４本を無効にする機能とかついていたりします。この「８本だけ有効」な場合に便宜上の**バイトアドレス**なるものを設けると 8bit CPU 時代のソフトウエアの技法を 32bit CPU でも使えて、ソフトウエア的には移行が楽になります。

さて 32bit を 8bit ごとにバイトアドレス付けすると下記のような図になりそうです。

```
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   +0                      +1                      +2                      +3 とアドレス付けすると BigEndian
   +3                      +2                      +1                      +0 とアドレス付けすると LittleEndian
```

ということで、１バイトのデータを必ず１バイト単位でアクセスする場合には、それによるハードウエア的違いはバス上の有効無効な位置が変わるだけであり、よってバイトオーダーなるものはソフトウエアから見えない＝ソフトウエア上は存在しないことになります。本文中の `read()` や `write()` は基本はこのように１バイトづつアクセスすることでバイトオーダーに影響を受けない動作を実現しているわけです。

8bit なデータをむりくり 16bit で見たり 32bit で見たりするとこの便宜上のバイトアドレスの配置順がバイトオーダーとかエンディアンとか呼ばれる違いとなってソフトウエア上からも見えることになります。

Answer (score -2):

char型は1バイトなので影響は受けません
影響があるのはintからshortへキャストする時などです
例えば900という値があります
16進数に直して384となるこの値は、メモリ内で次のように配置されます

リトルエンディアン　84 03
ビッグエンディアン　03 84

この16進数は2桁で1バイトなので4桁2バイトの並びだと判ります
数値型に置換すればshort型に相当します
ここで、この数値をshortからint_8tなど1バイト長の数値型にキャストすることを考えます

キャストでは先頭アドレスからの一定領域にあるアドレス内の値を見ます
今回は1バイトの領域を覗くので、リトルエンディアンなら84、ビッグエンディアンなら3を取得します
10進数に直してそれぞれ123と3です

これがバイトオーダーの挙動とその影響です
最初から1バイトで数値が表されるchar型には何も影響がありません

Comment: 符号無し整数の小さい型へのキャストは処理系のバイトオーダーと無関係であり、2のビット乗を加算・減算して求まる数値と同じになるように演算が行われます([キャスト演算子](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast)及び[暗黙の変換](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)を参照)。符号付き
整数の場合は処理系定義ですが、qemuを用いてppc64(ビッグエンディアン)+FreeBSD+gccの環境で検証したところ、符号無し整数と同じバイトの切り詰めを行っているようで、x86_64(リトルエンディアン)の環境と結果が同じ(0x86=-124)でした。本当に900をキャストして3になるような環境はあるのでしょうか？そのような動作をする環境のCPU/OS/コンパイラの組合せを教えてください。

Comment: ひとまず、手元の検証ではビッグエンディアンであっても3にはならなかったので、「 **この回答の内容は間違っている可能性が高い** 」としてダウン票を入れておきます。3になるような処理系を教えていただければ、アップ票を入れ直しますので、ご提示をお願いします。